# How to remove previous versions of Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

When the 3.2 beta of the iPhone OS first came out, Xcode for 3.2 had to be installed side-by-side with the version for 3.1.2.  I installed the new version (3.2) in /Developer and moved 3.1.2 to /Xcode3.1.2.  Now I want to get rid of the old version and just use the new one since we can do that now.

I ran the uninstall tool at /Xcode3.1.2/Library/uninstall-devtools and uninstall-developer-folder, but the directory still exists and has lots of stuff still in it, adding up to about 5 GB.  At this point, am I safe just deleting the folder if I want to totally get rid of it and still use the /Developer folder?

(At about 8 GB, it's got lots more in it, but I'm not sure if that's just because it's larger or because the old version was 8 GB before I ran the uninstall tool)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After running (DevToolsFolder)/Library/uninstall-devtools, there always seems to be something left over. I just delete the folder at that point and move forward.

However, in your situation -- moving forward from a beta, I always:

- run uninstall-devtools on *every* developer tools folder
- delete each developer tools folder
- reinstall the final/production version of developer tools

This isn't supposed to be necessary, but beta software installs are not always well behaved, and this process does a thorough cleanup.

Answer (score 7):

Just to be safe, did you run:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: well, no.  I ran /Xcode3.1.2/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all though

Comment: `/Developer-3.2.3/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember, the /Developer folder does not exist with a fresh OSX install.
It's created when the DevTools are installed.

So it should be safe to delete that folder, and re-install the DevTools.

Comment: I don't want to delete the /Developer folder, I want to delete the /Xcode3.1.2 folder which used to be the /Developer folder, and I'm wondering if will need to re-install  3.2 after I do, or if there's another approach